# Parameterized stored procedure skip if when zero is passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

I would like to be able to handle a parameter when zero is passed to the stored procedure. If the parameter is zero, we ignore the `AND` statement.

Here is my procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @WarehouseId INT = 0,
    @CreatedFromUtc DATETIME = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        [Deleted] = 0
        AND [WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId
        AND [CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
        AND [CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
END
```

I would like some kind of conditional where this part of the query is only run if the warehouse id is greater than 0

```
AND [WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId
```

Something like:

```
IF (@WarehouseId > 0)
    AND [WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId
```

I really need this, as in the database there are 3 warehouses, which ids 1, 2 and 3.

If I pass it as zero, my queries will fail as it won't match all 3 warehouses which I need to return if zero is passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
AND ([WarehouseId] = @WarehouseId OR @WarehouseId = 0)
```

Comment: Ahh yes that does it, whats the logic with that?

Comment: @chrisc . . . It is a simple `OR` condition.  That appears to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a case statement

```
    SELECT TOP 100 *
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] with (NOLOCK)

WHERE
    [Deleted] = 0

AND [WarehouseId] = case when @WarehouseId>0 then @WarehouseId else [WarehouseId] end
AND [CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')
AND [CreatedOnUtc] < ISNULL(@CreatedToUtc, '1/1/2999')
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: I can see this works too, so it deserves an upvote but I go with the answer from Gordon Linoff is what I will go with

Answer (score 1):

another option is to maximize the use of sqlserver `iif` function

```
and iif(@WarehouseId = 0, [WarehouseId], @WarehouseId) =  [WarehouseId]
```

Comment: @Metal  i get error ``` An expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected```

Comment: @chrisc, haha typo forgot the column, try again

Comment: Ahh yep now it works. However the solution you provided yeilds different results from the answer provided from Gordon Linoff. Do you know why ? Thanks

Comment: depends on your data. make sure you enclosed your conditions with OR

Comment: Well I can't decide who deserves the accepted answer lol, however the answer from Gordon yeilds the same results as when I take that statement out

Comment: if you have null values. it will be included

Comment: Oh as in included with the returned results?

Comment: yes, try this `SELECT TOP 100 *
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] where coalesce(WarehouseId, 0)  = 0`